# How can I have multiple DTO's for NestJS Request Body/Swagger

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, documentation

so I have a route that can accept two different DTO's. I'm having difficulty getting these two DTO's to link/show up on swagger. I'm using the swagger plugin with NestJS. I know in raw swagger you can do something like. Any ideas?

```
Request:
  oneOf:
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/RequestOneType"
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/RequestTwoType"
```

Any example of what I have right now is like

async initApp(@Body() req: RequestOneDto | RequestTwoDto , @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response) {

}

export class RequestOneDto {
@Length(1,10);
name: string

@Max(10)
value: number
}

export class RequestTwoDto {
@Length(1,15);
name: string

@Max(15)
value: number

state: 'New York'
}

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this way?

```js
@ApiExtraModels(RequestOneDto, RequestTwoDto)
@ApiBody({
  schema: {
    oneOf: [
      {
        $ref: getSchemaPath(RequestOneDto),
      },
      {
        $ref: getSchemaPath(RequestTwoDto),
      },
    ],
  },
})
async initApp(@Body() body: RequestOneDto | RequestTwoDto) {}
```

You can import `ApiBody, ApiExtraModels` from `@nestjs/swagger`

If you dont want to include the models explicitly you can register em in one place as

```js
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options, {
  extraModels: [RequestOneDto, RequestTwoDto],
});
```

And here is more [info](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#oneof-anyof-allof)

Comment: Thanks, yea I ended up doing it this way so it appears in swagger like this. But I found that having below actually takes out the validation. 
async initApp(@Body() body: RequestOneDto | RequestTwoDto) {}

Would you happen to know the best practice for validating the request body in this scenario?

Comment: I think union-type validations are not currently supported unless you do some custom implementations. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397445/nestjs-validate-request-body-using-class-validator-having-2-options-for-body-c)

Comment: does it gives propery type completion support during development? For exmaple: If the body have keys for RequestOneDto, tghen it show types for the only...

Comment: No, it won't be auto-inferring based on the payload. In the example, there is `body: RequestOneDto | RequestTwoDto` which means you need to explicitly typecast if you want to use either `RequestOneDto` or `RequestTwoDto` type values. If both DTOs share the same properties than it can be used without typecasting otherwise not.